# How to use `moment.js` with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, npm, momentjs

I am wanting to use momentjs with meteor.  This is an npm package, so from what I understand, it cannot be used with meteor because meteor uses it's own package system.  So here are my questions:

- Does anyone know of a way to use momentjs with meteor?
- Is there a way to use npm packages with meteor?

**2017 EDIT**: As of Meteor 1.4+, npm package management allows for standard imports of npm modules and named imports of Atmosphere modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For stand-alone js libraries like moment.js, validate.js, underscore.string.js, etc. you can just drop the source file into your `lib` folder. I use `client/lib` for libraries which will be used only on the client (like validate.js), and `lib` for libraries which could be used by both the client and the server (like moment.js).

If you use [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite), you can take advantage of the [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) packages. Some of what you are looking for for may be in there.

Using npm modules from meteor is something a lot of people ask about (for good reason). You can see some notes [here](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-about-nodejs-modules), though I heard first hand that the way meteor talks to npm packages is about to change significantly.

Comment: Brilliant!  I'd definitely like to request direct interaction with npm packages...

Comment: As David Weldon says, the Meteorite package manager is the way to go here.  http://atmosphere.meteor.com has a package for moment, which I've been using for months now with no problems.  Install Meteorite and then run `mrt add moment`, and you should be done.  The Meteor dev team is working on their own Meteorite-based package manager at the moment, so using atmosphere packages should be a good practice for the future, too.  As for npm packages, it's possible to use them in Meteor, but you have to be a bit careful to make sure the package will work inside Meteor's fibers on the server.

Comment: The only caution I would give about atmosphere packages is that some of them do not appear to be maintained. There are a couple of packages I use where the maintainer really stays on top of the latest version. On the other hand, many of the packages just look like abandonware. Long story short, you may want to do a little homework before running `mrt add`.

Comment: as of August 2014 all momentjs and momenttimezone packages on Atmosphere are obsolete. your best bet is to drop the latest versions in the lib folder

Answer (score 23):

Tyler, i had the same question and for sure many people where trying to find the right answer as soon as possible because this is a easy thing to do even though the people that are using meteor for the first time (as me) have this kind of questions...

**Meteor Package Management**

First of all we will wont be using NPM we will be using 'Meteor' which is been used from the Meteor Package Management [AtmosphereJS](https://atmospherejs.com/) Also, you will find other amazing packages here...

**So lets start**

Open your terminal and go directly where your App is, yo have to install the right dependencies to do so do this:

**Install the only dependency**

This will work with Meteor 1.*

```
 meteor add momentjs:moment
```

**Compile your app** (You can do it now or later)

This will add that package to your App, after that compile it again with

```
meteor
```

And go to any file inside of your isClient whichi is this

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {   }
```

and you can use the 'moment' method in the same way like they show on their website [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)!

**Example**

to give you an example, this is how i'm using in my meteor app

```
moment(dateToPass).fromNow();
```

because i'm using Mongo the original Data looks like this.

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2014-12-12T04:01:21.768Z")
```

i'll have to do a Simple find query to get it your data and then you can handle your data like this (This code will give you an idea of how i'm using the CreatedAt value that holds a Date() to use it with MomentJS)

```
var theItemsOnTheArray = SomeArray.find();
var dateToPass;
theItemsOnTheArray.forEach(function (item) { dateToPass = item.createdAt });
return moment(dateToPass).fromNow();
```

**The result will be**

```
// 3 years ago
// 2 years ago
// 21 hours ago
// in 3 hours
// 5 minutes ago
```

Instead of:

```
Thu Dec 11 2014 20:14:08 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

I hope its useful for any of you, if you think it has valuable info please +1 ;) thanks!

Comment: Really nice post. You include the version of Meteor, link to the momentjs examples, and use Markdown formatting tastefully. Plus 2 if I could :)

Comment: Amazing answer you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 6):

**2017 UPDATE** - Meteor 1.4+ uses `npm` modules with ES6. OP is from 2013.

Thus...

**The npm-only way:**

install [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) to your meteor project with `npm` and `import` in this manner...

```
$ cd /path/to/my/meteor/project
$ npm install --save moment

// inside your Meteor app files...
import moment from 'moment';
```

**The meteor-npm way with a blanket import:** (Thx, @Dave Gööck)

```
$ cd /path/to/my/meteor/project
$ meteor npm install --save moment

// Inside Meteor app...
import * as moment from 'moment';
// OR
import moment from 'moment';
```

More about Meteor-npm package imports [here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#importing-from-packages). (Specifically mentions `moment`).

Comment: This could be improved a bit. I was able to use import with meteor 1.5.1 by installing moment via npm: `meteor npm install --save moment` and importing it via `import * as moment from 'moment';` - Also the mentioned link is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

The question was asked 3 years ago, at that time there was no official package from atmosphere. Since the question was asked things changed and I point out when the package was added to meteor repos.

Install the official package from atmosphere

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```

if you are using typescript, just

```
import * as moment from "moment/moment";
```

then in your code

```
let date = moment(<some date>).format('YYYY MM DD');
```

Comment: The question was asked 3 years ago, at that time there was no official package from atmosphere.  As it stands now your answer is not very useful because it does not aboard the fact why OP needed to make the question.  If you outline in your answer that since the question was asked things changed and point out when the package was added to the meteor repos, then your answer will a very useful and noteworthy answer.

Comment: Don't forget to add "@types/moment" to your package.json so that you can use it without getting any warnings from the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I had a more complicated issue, because:

1. I wanted to add 'pl' locale
2. I needed it to work with TypeScript

I'd love to hear that there is an easier way to accomplish these goals, but 
here are steps which I did to finally make it work:

Step 1. `$ meteor add momentjs:moment`

Step 2. download the file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment-node.d.ts and save as in ./typings/moment/moment.d.ts (for some reason just performing `typings install dt~moment--global --save` will not do the trick, as it will only download an almost empty https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment.d.ts file which references the moment-node.d.ts file which contains the real stuff)

Step 3. append the following lines to moment.d.ts:

```
declare module "meteor/momentjs:moment" {
  var moment: moment.MomentStatic;
}
```

Step 4. download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/locale/pl.js (or any other locale) and save it in ./client/lib/moment/locale/pl.js (or any other directory below ./client)

Step 5. edit the begining and the end of the ./client/lib/moment/locale/pl.js replacing the loader code with a single line at the begining

```
import { moment } from 'meteor/momentjs:moment';
```

Step 6. finally you can use moment js in any of your modules, just append

```
import { moment } from "meteor/momentjs:moment";
```

at the begining of a file, and then you can do for example:

```
moment(ts).locale('pl').format('LLL');
```

If you are using 'meteor/tap:i18n' package, you might want to use the same language you passed to `TAPi18n.setLanguage(...);` during startup. You might need to create typings/globals/meteor_tap_i18n.d.ts file with

```
declare module "meteor/tap:i18n" {
  export var TAPi18n : TAPi18nStatic;
  interface TAPi18nStatic{
     setLanguage(name:string):any;
     getLanguage():string;
     __(name:string,params?:any):string;
  }
}
```

and then you can use it in your module with

```
import { TAPi18n } from 'meteor/tap:i18n';
//...
moment(ts).locale(TAPi18n.getLanguage()).format('LLL');
```