# Adding packages like moment.js & account.js to meteor Project

Tags: package, meteor, momentjs

How do I add these JS packages to a meteor project? Do I simply place the JS files in the public folder so the client and server can access them? Or is there some specific steps that I need to follow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i use momentjs with meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668993/how-do-i-use-momentjs-with-meteor)

Answer (score 5):

These kind of standalone libraries can be directly placed in the `/lib` directory under your project.

For use on both the client and the server, place them into `project/lib` folder.

Or if you want to use them only at client-side, place them as usual in `project/client/lib`

Answer (score 2):

In short, It depends.

I would recommend you check out http://atmosphere.meteor.com for a list of packages. If what you're looking for is there, install meteorite with `npm install -g meteorite` (https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite)

Once you have metorite installed you can install these community packages quite easily using `mrt add packagename`

Most packages are on http://atmosphere.meteor.com.

But if for some reason the JS package you want isn't on atmosphere, depending on the package,  if its a UI package (e.g datepicker, etc) put it in the `/client/lib` folder to avoid meteor crashing (only accessible by client).

If its a type of module abstractor (e.g backbone - backbone is included in meteor already btw: add using `meteor add backbone`) you could put it in the `/lib` directory of your package, it will be referenced automatically by both the server and client.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the packages via console.

Type "meteor add accounts-password" for example.

See [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#packages)

Perhaps you should watch some of these videos [here](http://www.eventedmind.com/)

to get an idea how meteor packages are added.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true: `meteor add` only allows you to add official packages. Moment.js is not an official package so that will not work. The correct solution have been listed here: one is to manually add the code in '/lib' and the other to use the Atmosphere package manager (not official).