# Form Input Validation with Meteor

Tags: meteor

Meteor doesn't have a built in validation smart package yet. What validation libraries should I consider? What are other people using?

Comment: I realize that you already know that, but form support is coming. The latest info (which you can still benefit from even if you decide to use David's good answer below), can be found at http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=RSASfz_vU2k

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We decided to use simpleSchema with Collection2 and autoform for validation. It's a very sophisticated solution. We save a lot of time using this approach rather than trying to roll each form by hand.

Simply by defining a scheme with validation rules (validation rules are provided automatically for data type and isRequired settings) then creating a form with autoForm (a single line of code) and you get all this for free

- An autogenerated form that uses bootstrap3 classes.
- Appropriate HTML5 fields for all keys in your collection schema.
- A submit button that gathers the entered values and inserts them into your collection.
- Form validation based on the schema attached to your collection. By default the form is validated when the user submits. If anything is invalid, the form is continually re-validated on keyup (throttled) as the user fixes the issues.
- Default validation error messages that appear under the fields, and can be customized and translated.

meteor-simple-schema
A simple, reactive schema validation smart package for Meteor.
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

meteor-collection2
A smart package for Meteor that extends Meteor.Collection to provide support for specifying a schema and then validating against that schema when inserting and updating. Also adds support for virtual fields.
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2

meteor-autoform
A smart package for Meteor that adds UI components and helpers to easily create basic forms with automatic insert and update events, and automatic reactive validation.
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform

Comment: With this approach you if you have different user languages it's a lot of work to setup each error message

Comment: why is that? Our app is fully multi-lingual. We use the messageFormat package for Meteor. Let me know where you are having to do a lot of work, and I'll try to help out. https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-messageformat/

Comment: how are showing different error messages in the correct lang?

Comment: HI @AlmogKoren, so in my simpleSchema schema I simply create custom error messages and define the text with messageFormat strings. example from my code: `schema.messages({
  invalidCardNumber: mf('cardNumberInvalid','Card number is invalid.'),
});` See here for more: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#customizing-validation-messages

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use [meteorite](http://oortcloud.github.com/meteorite/), you can just search through the [atmosphere packages](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) to see what's popular. I'm currently using [jqBootstrapValidation](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation). In the past I have used [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/), but right now I prefer to have something with bootstrap integration. I hear [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) is popular with the cool kids, though as of this writing there isn't a smart package for it - but that's easy enough to [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668993/how-do-i-use-momentjs-with-meteor).

Comment: so you can't install these packages with out-of-the-box Meteor? This Meteorite thing is required? Why is that? Because it's a non-standard package format or something? Cheers!

Comment: Meteor only comes with a handful of packages. You need meteorite in order to install packages created by the community. If you see the last link in my answer, it's easy enough to just include simple front-end libs into your project. So, no you don't need to install meteorite, but a lot of people run it because it makes installing packages easier, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

You already have `Tracker` as part of Meteor, so I put a little tutorial and JSfiddle together on how to use it to implement a typical form validation scenario.

http://bit.ly/meteor-form-validation-video

http://bit.ly/meteor-form-validation-fiddle

Comment: Hi Dean, have you tried using simpleSchema before? For a simple app with just a couple forms it might be overkill, but for a large app with many forms, we found it to be much more productive than the prescriptive approach where you have to implement all the details yourself. Check out this demo to see how much functionality you get with very minimal effort! https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#demo

Comment: Sometimes the form is not for a database you own, (or it's for an API call) so I intended to show how to roll your own. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Actually that's no matter, you can still use the schema to provide the validation whether it for a database you own or not. It doesn't actually write the data into mongo like an ORM or anything. You have control over that. We use simpleSchema and autoform even when validating payment information for Stripe API for example.