# MomentJs: moment is not defined in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs, meteor-helper

I am new in meteor. I doest add moment.js in my package. But I can see moment.js is included in my rendered page. I think moment.js included by any other package which is added by me. My question is I can't use that included moment.js. When I try to use moment.js Meteor says `Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: moment is not defined`.  What might be the problem?

[image]

**Js:**

```
Template.Home.helpers({
  fromnow: function(time){
    console.log(time);
    return moment(time).fromNow();
  }
});
```

Comment: This could be due the load order the javascript files in meteor.. How do you load momentjs?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668993/how-do-i-use-momentjs-with-meteor

Comment: @DennisStolmeijer: Moment.js is included in `Line 61`. I called `moment()` at `Line 81 home.js`

Comment: @BlueBells I ment how did you load the momentjs file as dependency. But try to remove the momentjs package ur using and directly save the file in the lib folder of you meteor app (if you want to use it both client and server side, otherwise in the client/lib folder)

Comment: @DennisStolmeijer: No momentjs package in meteor package. It might be dependencies of another package

Answer (score 3):

the simple answer to this is that you have to actually add that package to Meteor. The HTML source that you are showing is just the dependency indicator. You will have to add the package manually from command line.

command is as follows:

```
>meteor add momentjs:moment

momentjs:moment: Moment.js (official): parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates - official Meteor packaging
```

The above line indicates that the momentjs package is installed. So now, wherever you might have written the code for moment. It will start working.